# initializing property of structure

Tags: c

I'm new to c, and currently making chess program.

There's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int spider[8][2] = {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, 
                {0, -1}, {-1, -1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 1}};

int jump[8][2] = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {1, -2}, 
              {-2, -1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {-2, 1}};

typedef struct
{
    int color;
    int type;

    char symbol;

   int unit[8][2];
} piece;

void add_piece(piece piece, int color, int type, char symbol, int unit[8][2])
{
    piece.color = color;
    piece.type = type;

    piece.symbol = symbol;

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            piece.unit[i][j] = unit[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    piece wk;
    add_piece(wk, 0, 0, 'K', spider);

    printf("%d", wk.color);

    return 0;
}
```

expected output : 0

console output : 8388608

I found that 8GB = 8388608KB.

1. What's the meaning of that output?
2. Is there any problem of initializing property of structure or elsewhere?
3. Can you see some not good habits in this code?

Comment: You did not change the original variable. You changed a copy of it passed as the first parameter. You should pass a pointer to `piece`.

Comment: Functions arguments are passed by value in C (the function receives a copy of the argument)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*.

That means the *value* of the argument in the call is *copied* into the functions argument value.

So in the call

```
add_piece(wk, 0, 0, 'K', spider);
```

the value (current uninitialized contents) of the structure object `wk` will be copied into the argument variable `piece` inside the `add_piece` function.

When you modify the local argument variable, for example through an assignment like

```
piece.color = color;
```

you only modify the local copy. The original value used in the call will not be modified.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. *Return* the structure, and assign to a variable when doing the call; Or
2. Emulate *pass by reference* by using pointers.

Option number 2 is the most common it seems, so I will show it here.

First you need to modify the function to take a *pointer* to the structure object:

```
void add_piece(piece *piece, int color, int type, char symbol, int unit[8][2])
{
    ...
}
```

Then you need to use the "pointer to structure" syntax using the "arrow" to access structure members:

```
piece->color = color;
piece->type = type;
// And so on for all access to piece members...
```

Finally, when you call the function you need to pass a pointer to the `wk` variable, using the "pointer to" or "address of" operator `&`:

```
add_piece(&wk, 0, 0, 'K', spider);
```

---

I described the pass by reference emulation because it's so common and because you need to learn to recognize it. For your specific case I would rather recommend that you define a new structure object in the function and *return* it:

```
piece add_piece(int color, int type, char symbol, int unit[8][2])
{
    piece piece;

    piece.color = color;
    piece.type = type;

    // And so on, much like your current function...

    // Return the structure
    return piece;
}
```

Now you can use it as such:

```
piece wk = add_piece(0, 0, 'K', spider);
```

Note that sometimes it's not possible, or desirable, to return structures like this, and you still need to emulate pass by reference. So you need to learn both ways.

---

Lastly a note about the output you get: Uninitialized local (non-static) variables really *are* uninitialized. They will have *indeterminate* (read: garbage) values.

Since in your current code doesn't really initialize the original `wk` structure object, all its members will have such indeterminate values.

Depending on type and use, using such indeterminate values could lead to *undefined behavior*.